# Can't add background image to scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried dragging the image asset into the Hierarchy... won't let me. I tried dragging it into the Scene... won't let me. What the hell is going on here?

This is a Unity 3D project. I've tried this in Unity 5.1 and Unity 4.3.

[image: Trying to drag-and-drop image into Unity Scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Unity in a while so you have my sincere apologies if this answer is inaccurate: I believe that the reason dragging and dropping hasn't worked is because there's nothing to drop onto.

You're dropping the image into an empty universe.

You need to create some surfaces (mesh/quad) for the images to apply to.

[Have a look here for a walkthrough.](https://youtu.be/ds9xhYHndXI)

Comment: That appeared to work.. however, I still don't see the image, even though I added it to a quad in my scene.

Comment: Hmm. This might sound silly, but have you checked under the bed? ;) By that, I mean, have you flipped the mesh? Meshes are 2 dimensional so there's a chance the image applied itself to the bottom side.

Comment: Yep! I just had to rotate it and move it in front of the camera! lol